# Is it possible to send a web push message from one browser to another?

Tags: web-push

Disclaimer: I know this is not the intention of web push! Normally there is a backend server which has the vapid keys and sends the http request to FCM. For my use case, security is not a consideration. I just want to know if it's possible to send the request directly to FCM from a different browser tab.

- Is there anything in browsers which will restrict this?
- Is there something in the spec which restricts this?
- Will FCM reject requests coming from a browser?

As a quick test, I tried embedding https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push but the library is intended for nodejs.

For context, I am trying to find a way to send a WebRTC answer to the offering peer without hosting a backend. The goal would be to issue a new vapid private and public key from the offering peer for each new RTCPeerConnection. I could then share the keys by encoding them in an URL which the answering peer could use.

Comment: "Is there anything in browsers which will restrict this?" Yes, security.

Comment: As you said the VAPID keys must be kept private on the server... so the answer is no for security reasons. If you give the private keys to a browser, a malicious user could read those keys and start spamming all your users with notifications...

Comment: Security is not a consideration @collimarco in my use case. I'm asking whether it's possible, not whether it is a recommended best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible as `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/...` does not return the necessary CORS headers. I haven't tested other push services, but they are also unlikely to return CORS headers.